# Clearcase: Automate the checkout comment of source branch while checking out destination branch

Tags: version-control, clearcase

I have made all my modifications in my branch and going to another branch(or main). I had given the detailed comments while I checked in my work branch. But with clearcase merge manager, I have to reenter the same comments again which is really tough. Are there some way to use the original comments of the corresponding source version of the element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [ClearCase Merge Manager](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_merge_wrk.htm), based on [`cleartool findmerge`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_findmerge.htm) shouldn't ask you for any comment, and perform all merges automatically (except for the non-trivial ones).

The [merge manager wizards](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.tutorial.doc/a_complete_findmgrwiz.htm) should allow you to merge automatically files and directories, and the merge comment should be a default one.